# Is it normal for installed PEX piping to be curved or bowed?

Tags: plumbing, pex

Red PEX is curling or bowing throughout the main hot water line from hot water tank feeding all the faucets and showers.  Is this normal?

Comment: If you mean it has curves in it, probably.  Pex is usually shipped in coils, so removing all curves so it is straight is hard, it will tend to coil back, if given a chance.   Can probably give it more support to structure(house) to straighten it more.

Comment: Has hot water been run through these lines?

Comment: Has it been attached to the structure, or is it just floating in space?

Comment: Add a picture so we see what you see

Comment: What type of pex? The pex I use has 3 layers one being aluminum and does not bend easily. Rolled it out flat (ish) and pipe clamps 18” apart no issue.

Comment: A picture would help a lot. PEX is usually sold in rolls of 100 feet or more so unless you're sending it through floor joists then it's difficult to get the bow out of it.

Comment: Where are seeing the pipe that you can tell that it's curved? Including some pictures would really help a lot, but, in most cases, this isn't a problem.

Comment: Is your question about the static state of the tubing or movement that has occurred after installation? Your post title and question don't jive.

Answer (score 3):

It is most likely fine. As others have pointed out, PEX comes coiled and it is completely acceptable to have it installed with curves and arcs, like this:

[image]

PEX is not like copper or iron pipe. Rigid pipe is... well... rigid, so we get used to thinking of plumbing as begin built from straight sections, but that isn't the case with PEX. I'm assuming the installation you are looking at is otherwise properly installed and supported, and the only part that has you concerned are some wide bends/curves. If that is correct, it's completely normal.

Comment: Your answer is correct.   I however find a lot of issues with that picture - and I understand it isn't "finished"... but I would not use that picture of an example of how pex is run on interior walls.

Comment: @DMoore Fair enough. The original photo I posted was only meant to illustrate that a PEX installation can look very different from what you'd get with copper in the same space. It was not intended to be an example of overall quality plumbing work. I change it to one that is a little better (I hesitate to call any PEX installation "good", but if code allows it, then my opinion is just that).

Comment: I agree but that picture is a lot better.   The amount of area unprotected and unsecured was a little much on that last picture.   Just didn't want that to represent a normal install.   Curving... for sure.   There is a max bend that you can have and also a bracing rules for 90 degrees.